# How do I add a synchronized clip/angle to a multi-cam clip?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, multi-camera

I selected a 10 clips of the same event and [created a new Multicam clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmFmyXWaQHM). The videos aligned perfectly via **Use audio for synchronization**. I edited the entire clip and chose different angles at the exact times I want them to show. Everything is great.

Problem is I just found another clip that should have been added, but I forgot to add it (i.e. I should have 11 clips in the multicam clip, not only 10). I want to add this 11th clip and tweak the multicam clip a bit to show it at certain times. I don't want to restart the process as 90% of my work is already done.

I know I can add a new angle and drag the clip in there, but the problem is I would have manually "synchronize" it, by dragging it in the correct location. I don't see any way to choose to synchronize it (e.g. via audio).

I see **Clip > Synchronize clip**, but that is disabled, and I wouldn't even know which two or more clips I should choose.

How do I add a new clip/angle to an existing multicam clip, and have it automatically synchronize its position via audio?

Comment: Manually syncing 1 clip via audio doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: Going from 10 to 11 is just one example, might need to go from 10 to 16 for example.

Answer (score 3):

One (probably dumb) way to do this is:

1. Select all 11 clips again and create a new, temporary Multicam clip.
2. Double-click the temporary multicam clip and find out the exact [timecode](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12558?locale=en_US) where the new, 11th clip was added.
3. Copy the 11th clip.
4. Delete the newly created temporary multicam clip
5. Double-click the original multicam clip
6. Navigate to that exact same timecode
7. Paste the clip into that location